# Controller validation in Kotlin Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a RestController with one endpoint. That endpoint accepts object of data class. Data class has 2 attributes. How do I make sure these attributes are validated?

My data class:

`data class FormObject(val email: String, val age: Int)`

And controller:

```
@PostMapping("submit")
fun submit(@RequestBody formObject: FormObject): FormObject {
    return formObject
}
```

How do I make sure email is email and age is not bigger than 150?
Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Bean Validation Framework for this.

1) Annotate the request object as needing validation:

```
fun submit(@Valid @RequestBody formObject: FormObject): FormObject
           ^^^^^^
```

2) Annotate the fields of your data class with the appropriate validation annotations:

```
data class FormObject(
    @field:NotBlank 
    val email: String, 

    @field:Min(1) 
    @field:Max(150) 
    val age: Int
)
```

Note that you have to apply the annotation to the `field` (not the parameter) or the validation won't happen the way we want. Also, if we define `age` as an `Int`, it will have a default value (`0`) if the caller does not send it, so I applied a the minimum validation on that to offset that (assuming age 0 is not ok, YMMV).